# MS Access Macro to change form to No data entry

Tags: ms-access, macros, ms-access-2003

I need a Macro (preferably SendKey) command to change datasheet form from data entry to no data entry.

Comment: Do you mean you want to make an Access form read-only (ie set AllowEdits = false)  from an external source? Do you have the code for the Access form?

Comment: Its a datasheet sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
frm.AllowEdits = False
frm.AllowAdditions = False
frm.AllowDeletions = False

frm.DataEntry = False
```

Note that the `DataEntry` property does NOT say whether you can edit or not. If it is set to `True` the form will open on a new empty record instead of showing actual data. `DataEntry` is disabled by default.